# How to remove specific identifier using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

How can I remove specific identifier and change the element tag using xslt? For example, if the value of the output contains identifier "ALPHA", I need to remove it in the output value and the tag name will become `<Alpha>`. If it contains identifier "ZERO", the element tag will become `<Zero>` and remove the identifier ZERO in the output.

**EXAMPLE**:

```
<Data>
    <Element>01ALPHA</Element>
    <Element>Geraldine AnneALPHA</Element>
    <Element>012345ZERO</Element>
</Data>
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**:

```
<Data>
    <Alpha>01</Alpha>
    <Alpha>Geraldine Anne</Alpha>
    <Zero>012345</Zero>
</Data>
```

Thank you. Your feedback is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Element[ends-with(., 'ALPHA')]">
    <Alpha>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(., 'ALPHA')"/>
    </Alpha>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Element[ends-with(., 'ZERO')]">
    <Zero>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(., 'ZERO')"/>
    </Zero>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi @Michael.hor257k, thank you so much for your feedback.